# How to retrieve data from model using findByType in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to find records from **CallForwardingCondition** model using following line of code:

```
$this->loadModel('CallForwardingCondition');
$this->set('callForwardingCondition', $this->CallForwardingCondition->findByType('list'));
```

In SQL Dump following query is done when page is reloaded:

```
SELECT `CallForwardingCondition`.`type`, `CallForwardingCondition`.`description` FROM `vpbx`.`call_forwarding_condition` AS `CallForwardingCondition` WHERE `CallForwardingCondition`.`type` = 'list' LIMIT 1
```

How can I direct Cakephp to findByType which will result in following query?

```
SELECT `CallForwardingCondition`.`type`, `CallForwardingCondition`.`description` FROM `vpbx`.`call_forwarding_condition` AS `CallForwardingCondition` WHERE `CallForwardingCondition`.`type` LIKE '%' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I am using CakePHP v2.10.0-RC1

Comment: OK, thanks. I've added an answer appropriate to your version of CakePHP. Ajay's answer is for CakePHP 3. Always mention the version you are using when you post questions in future as it helps people give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For CakePHP 2.x you need to use `find('all')` and pass it the required conditions and `limit`:-

```
$result = $this->CallForwardingCondition->find('all',[
    'conditions' => ['CallForwardingCondition.type Like' => '%'],
    'limit' => 10
);
```

`findByType` is a special find method that will only return the first record matching the `type` passed as the find method's parameter which is why it isn't returning what you want. You can read more about the `findBy` magic functions in the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $result = $this-> CallForwardingCondition ->find('all',['limit'=>10,'conditions'=>['CallForwardingCondition.type Like'=>'%'])->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can't use `findBy` with limit. If you want to use limit, you must use `findAllBy<fieldName>`. Even `findAllBy<fieldName>`, you can't use `LIKE`.

This is [findAllBy](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findallby) from cakephp

```
findAllBy<fieldName>(string $value, array $fields, array $order, int $limit, int $page, int $recursive)
```

So if you want to covert it, you must do the following way;

```
 $this->CallForwardingCondition->findAllByType('something',['CallForwardingCondition.*'],['CallForwardingCondition.id'=>'desc'],'10');
```

This is [findBy](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findallby) from cakephp doc.

```
findBy<fieldName>(string $value[, mixed $fields[, mixed $order]]);
```

Hope this help for you.